# Checkbox to trigger input, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am currently working on a form, and am required to do the following:

If the checkbox next to the input field (in this case, a qty field) is checked, then set the input to "1". If the qty field is greater than one, then the checkbox remains checked.

If the checkbox is unchecked, then the qty field is reset to 0. Alternatively, if the user inputs 0 into the qty field, then the checkbox is also unchecked

**Problems**

- The increase button currently requires two clicks to increment the qty
- When the qty field has a number > 0, and is then decreased to 0, the increase button no longer works.

Can anyone spot the error in my ways?

```
jQuery('.exhibitorBooking--table .desc input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        if(this.checked){
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('.qty-field input[type="text"]').val('1');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('.qty-field input[type="text"]').val('0');
        }
    });
    jQuery('.exhibitorBooking--table .qty-field input[type="text"]').on('change', function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == 0){
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
        } else if(jQuery(this).val() == 1) {
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change').attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01s04dw4/)

Comment: Your second block is comparing the input of a textfield, which is text. You have to compare with `"0"` and `"1"` rather than `0` and `1`

Comment: Also you should query the checkbox and input element once with a jQuery selector and then store it in a local variable, rather than performing the same search a dozend times.

Comment: your code works but you'll need to change .attr to .prop at checkbox. Thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkStand-1-1').on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
        $('.input-text').val(value);
    });

    $('.input-text').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#chkStand-1-1').prop('checked', (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 0));
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/01s04dw4/1/

Comment: @daremachine No! It should be `prop`

Comment: @Tushar sorry it wasn't comment of your code, your code is fine ofc. My apologize.

Comment: @Tushar Just a quick issue I have with this now - Is there any way I can trigger the change event on the checkbox #chkStand-1-1 whenever  the text input box is changed? When I try to add the trigger in, everything stops working